# jQuery UI inline datepicker button disappears when setting minDate

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

Selecting a date from the first datepicker causes the "close" button to disappear from the second datepicker. Here is a fiddle of the issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/ssad0s2s/

Setting the minDate of datepicker2 in datepicker1's onSelect method is causing the issue. Please help!

HTML

```
<div id="datepicker1"></div>
<div id="datepicker2"></div>
```

JS

```
$('#datepicker1').datepicker({
        firstDay: 1,
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        showButtonPanel: true,
        currentText:"Close",
        onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
            $("#datepicker2").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);    
        }
});

$('#datepicker2').datepicker({
        firstDay: 1,
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        showButtonPanel: true,
        currentText:"Close",
});
```

Comment: If minDate is greater than the current date, then the "close" button will vanish

Answer (score 1):

What is the use case for the close button if you are showing the datepickers by default? Using inputs instead of divs has a done button to close the datepicker when finished which makes sense. However, having a close button when the datepicker cannot be closed seems like there is something missing from the question.

```
<input id="datepicker1"/>
<input id="datepicker2"/>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tomanow/ssad0s2s/1/)

**UPDATE**

A better solution for cross-device compatibility via [WebShim polyfill](http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/#Forms-forms-ext):

include these scripts:

```
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/webshim/1.14.2/minified/extras/modernizr-custom.js
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/webshim/1.14.2/minified/polyfiller.js
```

Add this as well:

```
    window.webshims.setOptions("forms-ext", {
        replaceUI: true,
        "date": {
            openOnMouseFocus: true,
            calculateWidth: false
        },
        "datetime-local": {
            openOnMouseFocus: true,
            calculateWidth: false
        },
        "number": {
            "classes": "hide-inputbtns"
        }
    });

    window.webshims.polyfill('forms forms-ext');
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tomanow/ssad0s2s/2/)**

Comment: That's a good point. I went down the inline datepicker route as I thought it would be trickier to position a popup datepicker on a responsive site.  I'm not showing the datepickers by default, I just wrote the code above to highlight the issue.

Comment: You could always use the HTML5 `<input type="date" />` without using datepicker and throw in some [WebShim](http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/#Forms-forms-ext) ;)

Comment: That's a nice looking datepicker :-)